# MS Access form not allowing additions with SQL Server Backend

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am having problems with an Access Front-End form not allowing additions, even though additions are checked. Before the backend conversion this worked fine, but now it does not.

#### Background -- **IMPORTANT**

I have been working on a project that has involved exploring a tool called SSMA to move an Access back end to SQL Server and for it to function with the same Access front end. I have been working to re mediate issues with the front end for it to do so. All of the data connections are fine to all the tables, most of the front end functionality works fine but one error I am trying to diagnose has been very hard to fix.

I have a form/ subform that should pull up and allow a user to enter information, and also to click enter in datasheet view and add additional tuples. BEFORE the conversion this works fine. My NEW access front end file that is linked to SQL Server does not seem to allow additions. If data is already in the table, it will pull it up and allow updates to that information, and by right clicking the tuple can be deleted as well, but no additions are possible.  There is no * on the left. There are other forms and subforms in the front end set up like this but they all work fine. This one has the same properties as those. This datasheet is referencing two tables.

I have been looking for hours now trying to find the solution. Also never touched access or vb before this. Any help is much appreciated.

- Checkbox datatype is defaulted to 0 and allows nulls
- Access 2013 with ODBC connections to SQL Server Tables

Comment: Does the table allow inserts if you open the linked table derectly in Access (instead of the form)?  Post the SQL Server table DDL.  You can get this by scripting the table with SQL Server Management Studio https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

Comment: Access will not allow inserts if the RecordSource is pointing to a query that could generate inconcistency updates. Similarly, Access won't allow inserts to views. As David requeted, post your RecordSource and it's SQL that might help.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Yes I can make inserted by accessing the linked table in Access. After making those insertions I can also verify their success through SSMS accessing SQL Server.

Comment: @krishKM The Record Source looks something like this. I have boviously changed names but it follows this format 

SELECT ChildTable.ChildTableID, ChildTable.Obj1ID, ChildTable.Obj2, ParentTable.Obj3, ParentTable.Obj4, ParentTable.Obj5, ParentTable.Obj6, ParentTable.Obj7, ParentTable.Obj8, ParentTable.Obj9, ParentTable.Obj10, ChildTable.Obj11, ChildTable.Obj12, ParentTable.Obj13, ParentTable.Obj14, FROM ParentTable INNER JOIN ChildTable ON ParentTable.ChildTableID = ChildTable.ChildTableID;

Comment: @T.Ladd you must chagne the query to a left joiner and return * from the primary table (the one you are tying to insert)

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the solution provided by krish KM in a comment.

> Change the query to a left joiner and return * from the primary table
>   (the one you are tying to insert)

That (SELECT *,  instead of SELECT [col1], [col2], [etc.]) solved the issue for me.